# Where does a struct and the object of the struct belong in the class?

Tags: c#, object, struct

I am making a "vending machine" and I need to index the total sales, and the amount of drinks left in the machine. Right now I have it set up when the user click on the picture of the soda, it will do the logic. Here is the full class:

```
namespace _8_11
{

    struct Drink
    {
        public string Name;
        public float Price;
        public int Amount;
    }

    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        object[,] Cola = new object[,]
        {
            {"Coke", 1.00f, 20 },
            {"Beer", 1.00f, 20 },
            {"Sprite",1.00f, 20 },
            {"Grape", 1.50f, 20 },
            {"Cream", 1.50f, 20 }
        };

        float total = 0.00f;

        private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Drink Coke = new Drink();

            Coke.Name = (string)Cola[0, 0];
            Coke.Price = (float)Cola[0, 1];
            Coke.Amount = (int)Cola[0, 2];

            if (Coke.Amount > 1 && Coke.Amount <= 20)
            {
                Coke.Amount -= 1;
                total += Coke.Price;
                cokeLeftLabel.Text = Coke.Amount.ToString();
                totalSalesLabel.Text = total.ToString("c");
            }
            else {
            MessageBox.Show("We are out of Coke!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The main problem is that the code:

```
Drink Coke = new Drink();

Coke.Name = (string)Cola[0, 0];
Coke.Price = (float)Cola[0, 1];
Coke.Amount = (int)Cola[0, 2];
```

When ever the user click the picture, these variables are reset. I need to initialize these variables outside of the clicked method, but when i try to move them outside this method it gives a compiling error "Coke.Amount does not exist in this current context".

I fixed it. Here is the revised code:

```
if (Coke.Amount > 0 && Coke.Amount <= 20)
        {
            Coke.Amount -= 1;
            Cola[0, 2] = Coke.Amount;
            total += Coke.Price;
            cokeLeftLabel.Text = Coke.Amount.ToString();
            totalSalesLabel.Text = total.ToString("c");
        }
```

Comment: Create a public Drink variable in the Class, this will make it available to all methods outside in the class. If you also make it static, this will also make it available to other classes. Have you tried doing this?

Comment: Your immediate problem is with scoping, but note that there is no reason to use a `struct` in this case, and it causes more problems than it solves.  If you change `Drink` from a `struct` to a `class` you will avoid a lot more problems that mutable structs create..

Comment: If your teacher told you to use a two dimensional array for this, he's criminally insane. You should still do the assignment as he says, but just remember to decline politely if he invites you to inspect his shipping container.

Comment: @EdPlunkett Yeah this is my books instructions. i could easily get this done with out a 2d array.

Comment: @vipersassassin I've tried making new classes, and new methods putting the new object inside of it but its always the same error: Coke,Amount is outside the current context.

Comment: @DStanley I am not sure how to use a class in the same way the struct is being used, can you point me to a tutorial page that does this?

Comment: Just change `struct Drink` to `class Drink`.  The usage syntax is exactly the same, but when you mutate (change the value of) a struct the behavior is very different.  You can read [the guidelines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229017.aspx) on when to use `struct` over `class`.

Comment: Also if you have code that currently is not working and want help with it, then _show that code_.  Otherwise we need to guess at what you've got based on your description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
List<Drink> drinks = new List<Drink>
{
  new Drink("Cola", 1.5f 20),
  //...
}

private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Drink drink = drinks[0];//Get the correct drink
  drink.Amount--;
   //...
```

Comment: The book says I need to use a 2d array.

Answer (score 1):

I usually create a custom picture box like the code below

```
public class DrinkPictureBox : PictureBox
{
    Drink drink = new Drink();

    public DrinkPictureBox(string Name, float Price, int Amount)
    {
        drink.Name = Name;
        drink.Price = Price;
        drink.Amount = Amount;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try pulling the declaration of the variable into the class

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        internal Drink Coke = new Drink();
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Coke.Name = (string)Cola[0, 0];
            Coke.Price = (float)Cola[0, 1];
            Coke.Amount = (int)Cola[0, 2];
        }
    }
```

Then, declare the initial constraints during Form1. This should give visibility to both Form and Events. I tried to do this, and have no issues from it.